# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl/knaw/dans/common/dbflib/CorruptedTableException

Tags: java, netbeans, dbf

I have a DBF database, and I'm working on it with Java using NetBeans. I used [this](https://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) library to work on DBF File. It works fine but after building, the jar throws the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl/knaw/dans/common/dbflib/CorruptedTableException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.CorruptedTableException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I used this command to run the jar:

```
java -"jar" SPM.jar
```

Comment: Class path problem.

Comment: how do I fix it?